# Can't filter product collection by type_id

Tags: magento

I'm observing the **catalog_product_collection_load_before** event and trying to filter the product collection based on its type_id. However, I keep getting **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in 'where clause** error.

The code is like this:

```
$observer->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'price',
        'eq'      => '20',
        ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'type_id',
        'neq'       => 'simple',
        ),
    ));
```

I even tried to make it more simple like this, but still doesn't work.

```
$observer->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('type_id','simple');
```

It works for other attributes such as price, name, entity_id, but not type_id. Why is that?

Comment: have u found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

try this piece of code in collection.

`$collection->getSelect()
->joinInner(array(’cpe’ => ‘catalog_product_entity’),’e.entity_id = cpe.entity_id’) 
->where("cpe.type_id = ‘simple’");`

don't use `addAttributeToFilter`,because in this when filtering via price, the main table has become `catalog_product_index_price`, so we can able to filter via `type_id`, the above code works well for me.

Please try this.

Comment: Awesome. This is the only solution for this issue that works.

Answer (score 0):

try code below if it works for you:

```
$observer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))->load();
```

Comment: I got **Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!** error. The last stack is **Mage_Core_Model_Store->getId( )..\Store.php:673**. This even doesn't work for any other attribute such as name, price.

Answer (score 0):

try below code, it can help you :

```
$observer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
          array(
           'attribute' => 'price',
           'eq'      => '20',
          )
        )
    )
    ->load();
```

Comment: addAttributeToFilter and addFieldToFilter are basically the same method because in Varien_Data_Collection_Db, addFieldToFilter() is mapped to addAttributeToFilter(). When you call either of these methods twice you're making AND operation. I need OR operation.